# No me habiita los textbox al darle clic al botón de agregar nuevo o clic al botón de modificar

Tags: java, java-swing

```
/*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package formularios;

    import clases.Datos;
    import clases.Usuario;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author HENRY
 */
public class frmUsuarios extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    private Datos misDatos;
    private int usuAct = 0;
    private boolean nuevo = false;

    public void setDatos(Datos misDatos){
        this.misDatos = misDatos;
    }
    public frmUsuarios() {
        initComponents();
    }


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    lblUsuario = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtIDUsuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    lblNombres = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtNombres = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    lblClave = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblPerfil = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtConfirmacion = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    cmbPerfil = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    btnPrimero = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnAnterior = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnUltimo = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnSiguiente = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnModificar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnBuscar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnNuevo = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnBorrar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnGuardar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnCancelar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    txtClave = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    txtApellidos = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    lblApeliidos = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblConfirmacion = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblCamposObligatorios = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setClosable(true);
    setIconifiable(true);
    setMaximizable(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setTitle("Usuario");
    setToolTipText("");
    addInternalFrameListener(new javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener() {
        public void internalFrameActivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameClosed(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameClosing(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameDeactivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameDeiconified(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameIconified(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameOpened(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
            formInternalFrameOpened(evt);
        }
    });

    lblUsuario.setText("ID Usuario *:");

    txtIDUsuario.setEditable(false);

    lblNombres.setText("Nombres *:");

    txtNombres.setEditable(false);

    lblClave.setText("Clave *:");
    lblClave.setToolTipText("");

    lblPerfil.setText("Perfil *:");
    lblPerfil.setToolTipText("");

    txtConfirmacion.setEditable(false);

    cmbPerfil.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Selecciones un perfil", "Administrador", "Empleado" }));

    btnPrimero.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/primero.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnPrimero.setToolTipText("Ir al primer registro");
    btnPrimero.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnPrimeroActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnAnterior.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/anterior.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnAnterior.setToolTipText("Ir al anterior registro");
    btnAnterior.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnAnteriorActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnUltimo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/ultimo.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnUltimo.setToolTipText("Ir al último registro");
    btnUltimo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnUltimoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnSiguiente.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/proximo.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnSiguiente.setToolTipText("Ir al próximo registro");
    btnSiguiente.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnSiguienteActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnModificar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/modificar.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnModificar.setToolTipText("Modificar registro");
    btnModificar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnModificarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnBuscar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/buscar.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnBuscar.setToolTipText("Buscar registro");

    btnNuevo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/nuevo.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnNuevo.setToolTipText("Nuevo registro");
    btnNuevo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnNuevoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnBorrar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/eliminar.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnBorrar.setToolTipText("Eliminar registro");

    btnGuardar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/guardar.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnGuardar.setToolTipText("Grabar registro");
    btnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
    btnGuardar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnGuardarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnCancelar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/cancelar.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnCancelar.setToolTipText("Cancelar acción");
    btnCancelar.setEnabled(false);
    btnCancelar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnCancelarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txtClave.setEditable(false);

    txtApellidos.setEditable(false);

    lblApeliidos.setText("Apellidos *:");
    lblApeliidos.setToolTipText("");

    lblConfirmacion.setText("Confirmación *:");

    lblCamposObligatorios.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 255));
    lblCamposObligatorios.setText("* Campos obligatorios");
    lblCamposObligatorios.setToolTipText("");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(50, 50, 50)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(lblCamposObligatorios)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(lblNombres)
                        .addComponent(lblUsuario)
                        .addComponent(lblApeliidos)
                        .addComponent(lblClave))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(txtIDUsuario)
                            .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                            .addComponent(lblPerfil)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(cmbPerfil, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 152, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(txtNombres)
                        .addComponent(txtApellidos)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(txtClave, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 91, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(lblConfirmacion)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(txtConfirmacion, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 166, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(14, 14, 14))))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(btnPrimero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnAnterior, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnSiguiente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnUltimo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnNuevo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnModificar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnBorrar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnBuscar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnGuardar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnCancelar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(88, 88, 88))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblUsuario)
                .addComponent(txtIDUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lblPerfil)
                .addComponent(cmbPerfil, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblNombres)
                .addComponent(txtNombres, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(txtApellidos, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lblApeliidos))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(txtClave, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(txtConfirmacion, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lblConfirmacion)
                .addComponent(lblClave))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(lblCamposObligatorios)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(btnPrimero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnAnterior, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnSiguiente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnUltimo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnNuevo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnModificar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnBorrar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnBuscar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnGuardar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnCancelar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    lblUsuario.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");
    lblNombres.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");
    lblClave.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");
    lblPerfil.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");
    btnPrimero.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");
    btnAnterior.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");
    btnUltimo.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");
    btnSiguiente.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");
    btnModificar.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");
    btnBuscar.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");
    btnNuevo.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");
    btnBorrar.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");
    btnGuardar.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");
    lblApeliidos.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");
    lblConfirmacion.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");
    lblCamposObligatorios.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");

    getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnNuevoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   //Habilita los botones
    btnPrimero.setEnabled(false);
    btnAnterior.setEnabled(false);
    btnSiguiente.setEnabled(false);
    btnUltimo.setEnabled(false);
    btnNuevo.setEnabled(false);
    btnModificar.setEnabled(false);
    btnBorrar.setEnabled(false);
    btnBuscar.setEnabled(false);
    btnGuardar.setEnabled(true);
    btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);

    //Habilita campos
    txtIDUsuario.setEnabled(true);
    txtNombres.setEnabled(true);
    txtApellidos.setEnabled(true);
    txtClave.setEnabled(true);
    txtConfirmacion.setEnabled(true);
    cmbPerfil.setEnabled(true);

    //Limpiar campos
    txtIDUsuario.setText("");
    txtNombres.setText("");
    txtApellidos.setText("");
    txtClave.setText("");
    txtConfirmacion.setText("");
    cmbPerfil.setSelectedIndex(0);

    //Activamos el flag de registro nuevo
    nuevo = true;

    //Damos foco al campo ID
    txtIDUsuario.requestFocusInWindow();

}                                        

private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    //Validaciones
    if (txtIDUsuario.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe digitar un ID (nombre de usuario)");
        txtIDUsuario.requestFocusInWindow();
        return;
    }

    if (cmbPerfil.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe seleccionar un perfil");
        cmbPerfil.requestFocusInWindow();
        return;
    }

    if (txtNombres.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe digitar un nombre(s)");
        txtNombres.requestFocusInWindow();
        return;
    }

    if (txtApellidos.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe digitar un apellido(s)");
        txtApellidos.requestFocusInWindow();
        return;
    }

    String clave = new String(txtClave.getPassword());
    String confirmacion = new String(txtConfirmacion.getPassword());

    if (clave.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe digitar una clave");
        txtClave.requestFocusInWindow();
        return;
    }

    if (confirmacion.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Debe digitar una clave de confirmación ");
        txtConfirmacion.requestFocusInWindow();
        return;
    }

    if (!clave.equals(confirmacion)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "La clave y la confirmacion deben ser iguales");
        txtClave.setText("");
        txtConfirmacion.setText("");
        txtClave.requestFocusInWindow();
        return;
    }

    // Si es nuevo validamos que el usuario no existe
    int pos = misDatos.posicionUsuario(txtIDUsuario.getText());
    if (nuevo) {
        if ( pos != -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "El usuario ya existe");
            txtIDUsuario.requestFocusInWindow();
            return;
        }
    } else {    
        if ( pos == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "El usuario no existe");
            txtIDUsuario.requestFocusInWindow();
            return;
        }    
    }

    // Creamos el objeto usuario y lo agregamos a datos
    Usuario miUsuario = new Usuario(
            txtIDUsuario.getText(),
            txtNombres.getText(),
            txtApellidos.getText(),
            clave,
            cmbPerfil.getSelectedIndex());


    String msg = misDatos.agregarUsuario(miUsuario);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, msg);

    //Deshabilita botones
    btnPrimero.setEnabled(true);
    btnAnterior.setEnabled(true);
    btnSiguiente.setEnabled(true);
    btnUltimo.setEnabled(true);
    btnNuevo.setEnabled(true);
    btnModificar.setEnabled(true);
    btnBorrar.setEnabled(true);
    btnBuscar.setEnabled(true); 
    btnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
    btnCancelar.setEnabled(false);

    //Deshabilita campos
    txtIDUsuario.setEnabled(false);
    txtNombres.setEnabled(false);
    txtApellidos.setEnabled(false);
    txtClave.setEnabled(false);
    txtConfirmacion.setEnabled(false);
    cmbPerfil.setEnabled(false);

    //Limpiar campos
    txtIDUsuario.setText("");
    txtNombres.setText("");
    lblClave.setText("");
    txtConfirmacion.setText("");
    cmbPerfil.setSelectedIndex(0);
}                                          

private void btnCancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    //Habilita botones
    btnPrimero.setEnabled(true);
    btnAnterior.setEnabled(true);
    btnSiguiente.setEnabled(true);
    btnUltimo.setEnabled(true);
    btnNuevo.setEnabled(true);
    btnModificar.setEnabled(true);
    btnBorrar.setEnabled(true);
    btnBuscar.setEnabled(true); 
    btnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
    btnCancelar.setEnabled(false);

    //Deshabilita campos
    txtIDUsuario.setEnabled(false);
    txtNombres.setEnabled(false);
    txtApellidos.setEnabled(false);
    txtClave.setEnabled(false);
    txtConfirmacion.setEnabled(false);
    cmbPerfil.setEnabled(false);
}                                           

private void btnModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
   //Habilita los botones
    btnPrimero.setEnabled(false);
    btnAnterior.setEnabled(false);
    btnSiguiente.setEnabled(false);
    btnUltimo.setEnabled(false);
    btnNuevo.setEnabled(false);
    btnModificar.setEnabled(false);
    btnBorrar.setEnabled(false);
    btnBuscar.setEnabled(false);
    btnGuardar.setEnabled(true);
    btnCancelar.setEnabled(true);

    //Habilita campos
    txtNombres.setEnabled(true);
    txtApellidos.setEnabled(true);
    txtClave.setEnabled(true);
    txtConfirmacion.setEnabled(true);
    cmbPerfil.setEnabled(true);

    //Desactivamos el flag de registro nuevo
    nuevo = false;

    //Damos foco al campo ID
    txtNombres.requestFocusInWindow();
}                                            

private void formInternalFrameOpened(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {                                         
    mostrarRegistro();
}                                        

private void btnPrimeroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    usuAct = 0;
    mostrarRegistro();
}                                          

private void btnUltimoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    usuAct = misDatos.numeroUsuarios() - 1;
    mostrarRegistro();
}                                         

private void btnSiguienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    usuAct++;
    if (usuAct == misDatos.numeroUsuarios()) {
        usuAct = 0;
    }
    mostrarRegistro();
}                                            

private void btnAnteriorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    usuAct--;
    if (usuAct == -1) {
        usuAct = misDatos.numeroUsuarios() - 1;
    }
    mostrarRegistro();
}                                           

private void mostrarRegistro(){
    txtIDUsuario.setText(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuAct].getIdUsuario());
    txtNombres.setText(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuAct].getNombres());
    txtApellidos.setText(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuAct].getApellidos());
    txtClave.setText(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuAct].getClave());
    txtConfirmacion.setText(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuAct].getClave());
    cmbPerfil.setSelectedIndex(misDatos.getUsuarios()[usuAct].getPerfil());
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnAnterior;
private javax.swing.JButton btnBorrar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnBuscar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnCancelar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnGuardar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnModificar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnNuevo;
private javax.swing.JButton btnPrimero;
private javax.swing.JButton btnSiguiente;
private javax.swing.JButton btnUltimo;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cmbPerfil;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblApeliidos;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblCamposObligatorios;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblClave;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblConfirmacion;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblNombres;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblPerfil;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblUsuario;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtApellidos;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtClave;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtConfirmacion;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtIDUsuario;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtNombres;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

[image: Al iniciar carga el primer registro en los textbox]
[image: Doy clic en modificar y no me habilita los botones]
[image: Doy clic en el botón nuevo y no me habilita los textbox]

Comment: Me parece que lo que te ocurre es que en el método `initComponents()` pones en editable false los JTextField (ej. `txtNombres.setEditable(false);`) y luego lo que haces es llamar al método `setEnable(true)`, debiendo llamar al `setEditable(true)`.

Comment: Su solución es OK. @E Betanzos, alguna razón para que no me limpie el txtApellidos cuando agrego un registro nuevo?

Comment: Si te refieres al método `btnGuardarActionPerformed()`, es porque no tienes en el código la llamada al `setText("")`.

Comment: @E Betanzos, impllemente lo que me indico en sus dos respuestas y quedó funcionando como lo necesitaba, igual le agregue el el método mostrarRegistro() en el botón    private void btnCancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) ya que si editaban el registro y luego oprimiaan el botón cancelar quedaba en el formulario con datos modificados en los textbox así no los agregaran, si coloca su respuesta la calificaré.

Comment: Acabo de colocar la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los campos de texto te impiden escribir en ellos porque en el método `initComponents()`, donde se crean todos los elementos de la interfaz gráfica, los pones en modo solo-lectura haciendo uso del método `setEdiable()` (ej. `txtNombres.setEditable(false)`). Luego en el métodos que utilizas estos campos de texto intentas habilitarlos para escritura llamando al método `setEnable()` (ej. `txtNombres.setEnabled(true);`) siendo lo correcto utilizar el método `setEdiable()` del siguiente modo `txtNombres.setEditable(true)`, ya que anteriormente se pusieron en modo solo-lectura, no se inhabilitaron.

Por otra parte, el tema de que algunos campos de texto no se limpian y otros si, se debe a que no has incluido el código necesario para hacerlo. Por ejemplo, en el método `btnGuardarActionPerformed()` no incluyes una linea como esta: `txtApellidos.setText("")`, razón por la cual este campo no se limpiará y el resto si.